# How to swap CMD and Control for Mac, but only in zsh/bash

Tags: bash, macos, zsh, iterm2

I'm using zsh inside iTerm2.

I want to go to the beginning of a line with CMD+A, 
inside vim if I want to go to normal mode with CMD+[

Basically everything that uses Control, I want to use CMD, and vice-versa.

I know I can do this in the iTerm2 settings, but then pasting into iTerm2 becomes Control+V instead of CMD+V, which is inconsistent with everything else in the system.

Basically I only want to remap them inside zsh, not for iTerm2.

I've tried xmodmap but the OS seems to ignore any settings I put there (OSX Sierra). Maybe I'm doing it wrong but I'm also worried that xmodmap would remap my OS bindings instead of just for zsh...

Comment: You're asking for two conflicting uses of the command key; how does iTerm2 know when CMD+V is paste and when it should be passed through to the process running in the window as Ctrl+V?

Comment: If you are looking to avoid typing the physical control key, consider swapping the control key and the *caps lock* key at the OS level. (Caps lock is easy to reach without moving your fingers out of normal typing position, and be honest: how often do you actually use the caps lock for the purpose of typing lots of capital letters in a row?)

Comment: So you want to selectively map `Cmd+A` but not `Cmd+V`. You can do this in the iTerm2 Key Mappings by adding a shortcut for `Cmd+A` with Action "Send Hex Code" value "0x01", and repeat for the other keys you want to map. Alternatively, you can flip the keys but add a binding for `Ctrl+V` to paste.

Comment: almost a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69516464/11107541